# Hiding Controlls in movi player

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can i hide controls (that play/pause next/previous) bar from my application movie?

Comment: Are you using MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: Oh Yes, i'm using that ant thanks for the answer.. by the way i used 'movieController.controlStyle = NO' and that too worked. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `MPMoviePlayerController` you can use its `controlStyle` property.

```
movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```